# Custom order and filter

Tags: xslt, sharepoint

I have a SharePoint list with news items. From that, I want to be able to select articles, and change the order of the selected items to make some kind of a newsletter.

I tried using a query-string to specify item-IDs and their order, something like this:

```
SortFilter.aspx?selection='i13o1,i5o2,i27o3,'
( i is for Item, o is for Order)
```

The filtering works ok, but I can't figure out how to sort using $elementLookup

```
<xsl:param name="QUERY_STRING" />
<xsl:variable name="string" select= 'substring-before(substring-after($QUERY_STRING, "&apos;"), "&apos;")'/>
<xsl:key name="myKey" match="Row" use="@ID" />
    <xsl:template match="/">                
        <xsl:for-each select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('myKey',@ID))]">
         <xsl:variable name="articleNumber">
            <xsl:text>i</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@ID" /><xsl:text>o</xsl:text>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="elementLookUp" select= 'substring-before(substring-after($string, $articleNumber), ",")'/>  
            <xsl:if test="$elementLookUp">  
               <xsl:value-of select="@ID" />
               <xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text>
               <xsl:value-of select="@Title" />  
               <xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text>  
               <xsl:value-of select="$elementLookUp"/>
           </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do so like this:

```
<xsl:sort 
    select="substring-before(substring-after($string, concat('i', @ID, 'o')), ',')"
    data-type="number" />
```

This expression will select the number that comes after `i<id>o`, and then you can sort on that.

After a bit of tidying, your stylesheet becomes:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:param name="QUERY_STRING" />
    <xsl:variable 
        name="selection" 
        select='substring-before(substring-after($QUERY_STRING, "selection=&apos;"), "&apos;")'/>
    <xsl:key name="myKey" match="Row" use="@ID" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each 
            select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('myKey',@ID)[1])]">
            <xsl:sort 
                select="substring-before(substring-after($selection, concat('i', @ID, 'o')), ',')"
                data-type="number" 
            />
            <xsl:variable name="articleNumber" select="concat('i', @ID, 'o')" />
            <xsl:variable name="elementLookUp" 
                select='substring-before(substring-after($selection, $articleNumber), ",")'/>
            <xsl:if test="$elementLookUp">
                <xsl:value-of select="@ID" />
                <xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="@Title" />
                <xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="$elementLookUp"/>
             </xsl:if>
         </xsl:for-each>
     </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```